# Multiple sign out methods in one function in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login, google-signin

I am wondering if I can or is an ok practice to bunch 2 methods for signing out (Facebook and Google) in one function call? I have a signout button and when a facebook user signs out sign out of Facebook, and of course when a Google user is logged in sign out of Google. Or should I create a conditional inside the sign out function? Thanks for any and all help!

```
 // handle sign out function
    func handleSignOut() {

        let firebaseAuth = FIRAuth.auth()
        do {
            try firebaseAuth?.signOut()
        } catch let signOutError as NSError {
            print ("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
        }

        // facebook sign out
        UserDefaults.standard.setIsLoggedIn(value: false)
        FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
        print("did log out of facebook...")

        // google sign out
        UserDefaults.standard.setIsLoggedIn(value: false)
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
        print("did log out of Google...")

        if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser == nil {
            let loginController = LoginController()
            present(loginController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be much problem with doing that but you would decrease the efficiency of the code as Firebase would still check if the other types of users are signed **even after** the user has signed out once. Again, this shouldn't be too much of a problem, but the benefits outweigh the cons of having a conditional inside the function. Anyway, it is very easy to do the conditional.